# convert numpy array into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a numpy array and I want to convert it into a dataframe.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
nparray = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])
```

How do I convert it into a dataframe where the data will be like this:

```
col1 col2
1      6
2      7
3      8
4      9
5      10
```

Comment: No I checked that answer before. But I wasn't able to understand how to transpose the array. I have got a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My favorite way to transform numpy arrays to pandas DataFrames is to pass the columns in a dictionary:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':nparray[0], 'col2':nparray[1]})
```

However, if you have many columns, you can try:

```py
# Create list of column names with the format "colN" (from 1 to N)
col_names = ['col' + str(i) for i in np.arange(nparray.shape[0]) + 1]
# Declare pandas.DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(data=nparray.T, columns=col_names)
```

In the second solution, you have to restructure your array before passing it to `data = ...`. That is, you have to rearrange `nparray` so that is has rows and columns. Numpy has a method for that: you simply add `.T` to your array: `nparray.T`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the below code to convert the numpy array into DF.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(nparray.T, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.DataFrame(nparray.T, columns=['col1', 'col2'])
```

That's it

Answer (score 1):

You can transpose your np array

### Creating the array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> nparray = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]])

>>> nparray
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10]])
```

### Creating the pandas DataFrame and transposing

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=nparray, index=["col1", "col2"]).transpose()

>>> df
   col1  col2
0     1     6
1     2     7
2     3     8
3     4     9
4     5    10
```

**In time** - Without transposing you would get this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=nparray, index=["col1", "col2"])

>>> df
      0  1  2  3   4
col1  1  2  3  4   5
col2  6  7  8  9  10
```